# What is the definition of a scalar?

Tags: field-theory, terminology

In physics a scalar is usually defined as a quantity wholly defined by a magnitude and no direction.  This is not a great definition, since a complex number is not a scalar under that definition.

A second definition of a scalar is a quantity that transforms as a scalar (e.g. is unchanged) under a change of coordinates. This allows for pseudo scalars, and is useful in teaching vectors and tensors to physics graduate students. However, I suspect that a mathematician would balk at this definition since it relies on coordinates.

A third definition is that "a scalar is an element of a field which is used to define a vector space."  However this has no content unless I am told what makes something an *allowed* element of a field.  Must it have certain properties like a commutative, closed, binary operation with an identity? Does the concept of a scalar exist independent of the concept of a field?

Comment: The third definition is the one that I use.  What makes something an "*allowed element of a field*" doesn't make sense to me... all elements of our field are scalars and the field itself is the set of scalars, referred to as the *scalar field*.  As for which *fields* are allowable as a scalar field, the answer is any field so long as scalar addition and multiplication is defined over your vector space.  As for what makes a particular set of elements a field in the first place, this is well documented already in any introductory book.

Comment: @JMoravitz I believe that comment can stand on its own as an answer :)

Comment: @JMoravitz I'd tweak this to say only that scalar multiplication needs to be defined on the vector space in such a way that it distributes over vector addition.

Comment: I just want to add that your first statement is somewhat misleading 'In physics a scalar ...' Sure, in high-school level physics, it is usually intuitive to explain it that way. In the same fashion a vector is defined as a thing with direction in basic algebra classes. But that doesn't imply a Mathematician defines a vector that way, nor does it imply that in Physics an scalar is considered to be a quantity wholly defined by a magnitude and no direction.

Comment: Do we really *need* a rigorous general definition of this term? To me this term seems to me to be one for which a general definition (for which there would for sure be exceptions wrt its use in certain contexts) would not be of much value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scalar-valued function definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286355/scalar-valued-function-definition)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834686/why-do-we-use-the-word-scalar-and-not-number-in-linear-algebra

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a situation where added generality yields more clarity.

Although in particular contexts only some vector spaces may be of interest, a vector space *in general* is just the following:

> A vector space is a triple $$(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{F},\cdot),$$ where
>
> - $\mathcal{F}=(F; +_F,\times_F,0_F,1_F)$ is a *field*,
> - $\mathcal{V}=(V; +_V)$ is a *group*, and
> - $\cdot$ is a function from $F\times V$ to $V$ satisfying the rules (for all $a,b\in F$ and $u,v\in V$)
>
>   - $1_F\cdot v=v$
>   - $(a+_Fb)\cdot v=(a\cdot v)+_V(b\cdot v),$
>   - $(a\times_Fb)\cdot v=a\cdot(b\cdot v)$, and
>   - $a\cdot (u+_Vv)=(a\cdot u)+_V(a\cdot v)$.

*Any* triple of this type is a vector space. In particular, any field can serve as the field of scalars of a vector space, and it's a good exercise to show that a field $\mathcal{F}$ is a vector space over itself in a natural way: take $\mathcal{V}$ to be the underlying additive group of $\mathcal{F}$, and take the scalar multiplication to just be the multiplication of $\mathcal{F}$.

When we're being more specific it should be clear from context what sorts of vector spaces are being considered. Often, for example, we're only interested in the case when $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{R}$. However, *in general* there's absolutely no restriction on what fields can serve as the field of scalars of a vector space.

---

There's a slight slipperiness here, though: what exactly are *elements of* fields? Sure, any field can be the field of scalars, but what sorts of things can be in fields to begin with? This gets to a "structuralist" aspect of mathematics: we don't care about what the underlying set of a structure - such as a field - actually is, but rather the behavior of that set together with the additional functions/relations/whatever. So anything whatsoever can be an element of the underlying set of a field, and so from a purely mathematical standpoint the question "what is **an individual** scalar?" isn't really meaningful. Of course, in particular situations we're often only interested in limited examples, and then we can say more - e.g. maybe we only care about subfields of $\mathbb{C}$, in which case we can get away with saying "all vectors are complex numbers," even though strictly speaking that's a bit bunk.

Comment: So by this definition the integers are not a set of scalars, because they don't have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @KieranMullen Well, the integers *with the usual arithmetic structure*, but yes.

Comment: The above answer has content answer is helpful - if your elements cannot be used to form a field then they are not scalars (under this definition).  I disagree strongly with the statement that the question is an empty one.  A scalar is a quantity that can support  the structure of a field.   Some quantities cannot and you can say that they are not scalars.

Comment: @KieranMullen It still doesn't make sense to ask whether an *individual thing* can be a scalar - any individual thing can be an element of a field. If $a$ is any object at all, pick any other object $b\not=a$; then $\{a,b\}$ is the underlying set of a field, indeed *two different* fields. So anything whatsoever can be a scalar - there is indeed nothing to say here. As to what *sets of* things can be the underlying set of a field, the only restriction is size: $X$ is the underlying set of some field iff $X$ is either infinite or of prime power size $\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question is similar to asking "what is a number." In different contexts one makes use of the counting numbers, the integers, the real numbers, the complex numbers, elements of the algebraic closure of Q in C, and so on. For a discussion about a specific problem to be productive, one must specify, if only for sake of convention, what is meant by a number, or what the set of numbers is that is being considered.

Therefore, in my opinion, if two physicists are speaking, and one says "Take lambda to be a scalar", we should understand this as follows: there is some ordered pair (F, V) that has gone unspoken between them; where F is a field, and V is an Abelian group, and F acts on V in a way satisfying the vector space axioms. The precise choice of F and V may be irrelevant, if they are merely discussing abstract linear algebra, or it may be very important that F is some specific field like complex numbers, and V is a specific space like a signal space, if a concrete problem is at hand. In any case, a scalar is an element of the field F being implicitly or explicitly discussed.

Comment: If you cannot say what a scalar *is* can you tell when something is not a scalar?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. I am telling you that *in the context* of a fixed pair $(F,V)$, where $F$ is a field and $V$ is a vector, I define a scalar to be an element of the field. You asked if the notion of scalar makes sense outside of the notion of a field (or ring): arguably, the answer is no.